# What do the text annotations in an electron micrograph mean?

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, cell-membrane, microscopy

I saw a photograph taken from an electron microscope, with some text.

[image]

I want to know what is the meaning of these numbers and letters?

Thank you! Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `1.40kX` is the zoom (1400x), `WD` is the working distance (distance between the final lens and the object), `20kV` is the voltage used to accelerate the electrons, `20μm` is the scale.

I'm not aware of the other two.

Comment: Thank you! if the voltage increase, what will be the effect on the picture?

Comment: @French_FitGirl The voltage is used to accelerate electrons. High velocity electron beam would have a higher resolving power. However low voltage is often preferable for SEM. You can read more about electron microscopy.